# Есть ли хорошая книга по написанию библиотек?

Tags: c++, книги

Чтобы было разжевано в подробностях как создать библиотеки `lib/dll` или все плюсы и минусы их использования и т.д. Ну и примеры на `C++`. 
Пытался найти какую-то книгу, но натыкался только на статьи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> но натыкался только на статьи

конечно только на статьи. Вы бы еще поискали книгу "Синтаксис оператора if в пяти томах". Что по-вашему должно быть в целой книге, посвященной такой узкой теме, заслуживающей от силы одной главы?

На всякий случай резюмирую: таких книг скорее всего нет, а если и есть, то  наверняка это несусветная дичь, автор которой при написании своего опуса для увеличения числа страниц в нем активно пользовался методом "copy-paste" и трюком Маяковского. Для понимания сути вашей проблемы и ее решения вполне достаточно ряда статей, кои в великом множестве можно найти в интернетах

Comment: Предполагал такой ответ:). Пока [этого][1] хватило 


  [1]: http://wm-help.net/books-online/book/59464/59464-12.html#h19

Comment: [оффтопик] А что такое "трюк Маяковского"? Гугл выдал 1 ссылку на историю про кольцо для Лилички.

Comment: Как такового "трюка Маяковского" история не знает. Это я так выразился. Дело в том, что пролетарский поэт очень любил писать стихи "лесенкой". Яркий пример:

>Мой стих
>    трудом
>       громаду лет прорвёт
>и явится
>    весомо,
>       грубо,
>          зримо,
>как в наши дни
>      вошёл водопровод,
>сработанный
>     ещё рабами Рима.

А так как поэтам в то время в советских журналах платили за каждую строку, то получалось, что Маяковский получал больше денег за одинаковый объем, за что подвергался некоторыми поэтами обвинениям в жульничестве. Впрочем, было эли это на самом деле, не знаю

Comment: Да ладно, Маяковский так начал писать еще до революции.

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что он  так писал только из соображений выбить побольше денег. Иначе он был бы мелким жуликом, а не советским классиком

Comment: Ошибаетесь. Для .NET, например, есть отличная книга Framework Design Guidelines (http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5588868/). Думаю, многое оттуда применимо и к разработке нативных библиотек.

Comment: @andreycha 

>Думаю, многое оттуда применимо и к разработке нативных библиотек

1) крайне смелое допущение

2) 404

Answer (score 4):

Ну, не книга, конечно, но полсотни страниц под названием

["How To Write Shared Libraries"](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Правда, для *nix.

--

А вообще, было бы интересно почитать что-то вроде "Искусство разработки библиотек". Естественно, я не имею в виду ключи ld, ar и т.п., а скорее рассказы разработчиков популярных библиотек о том *почему* они реализовали именно данный набор функций.

Answer (score 2):

Есть замечательная книга по проектированию .NET библиотек, называется [Framework Design Guidelines](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321545613). Примеры на C#, и культура там тоже .NET-ая передается. Но, с другой стороны, разработка удобных в использовании библиотек - это задача слабо зависит от языка. Поэтому там вы найдете массу полезных вещей.

Например, там неоднократно говорится о важности удобства использования библиотекой. Хорошая библиотека позволяет делать простые вещи - просто, а сложные - возможно. Это то, чего многим библиотекам, кстати, не хватает.

Там достаточно плотно проходятся по стандартам и идиомам кодирования, которые отличаются от языка к языку, но общую идею в этой книге перенять будет можно.

Comment: "Например, там неоднократно говорится о важности удобства использования библиотекой. " многочисленные рекомендатели парсить ML регекспами с вами несогласны, более того, активно сопротивляются такому подходу. Попробуйте их убедить в том, что они - идиоты, и у вас материала не на одну книжку наберётся. По психологии.

Comment: Не совсем понял, поскольку причинно-следственная связь not detected:) Многими .NET библиотеками достаточно удобно пользоваться, но далеко не всеми. И я не говорю за Microsoft Patterns and Practices, которые убоги чуть более, чем полностью, я говорю за конкретную книгу, которая очень даже хороша и подходит под требования топикстартера (за исключением того, что она для C#/.NET, а не для С++).